Mallet with German Texts
When I use MALLET with German texts, my own or the texts proposed by MALLET itself, I never get a correct import, always letters as äöü are missing respectivly written in a false way. Trying --encodig UTF-8 does not help.
I'm working with windows 11.
I would appreciate a hint how to get a correct representation of German texts.

Here are few steps to fix this:

Check File Encoding: Make sure your text files (.txt, etc.) are saved in UTF-8 encoding. Use editors like Notepad++ to convert and confirm the encoding (Encoding -> Convert to UTF-8).

Specify Encoding in MALLET Commands: When running MALLET commands, include --encoding UTF-8 to ensure it reads special characters correctly:


mallet import-file --input input.txt --output output.mallet --encoding UTF-8

Ensure you're using the latest MALLET version for improved character encoding support.

Start with a basic text file containing German umlauts to verify MALLET handles them correctly.

Verify your system's locale settings support German characters. Adjust them if necessary in Control Panel -> Region -> Administrative tab -> Change system locale.



Mallet assumes UTF-8 by default, and the provided examples in German are definitely UTF-8 encoded. It's also rare these days to see any docs not in UTF-8. This makes me think the only remaining issue could be something with the operating system or the JVM. If you give --help to the Mallet import command, it will tell you the default encoding under the --encoding option, which could help debug. But I'm not sure why setting that variable wouldn't override that.

Thanks. Is it possble, that only the x.mallet-file looks not utf-8 conform, but the output at the end is ‚correct‘ again?
